# Mobile devices detect

Tags: php, mobile, device, detect

I have some page, but i need that users with randow user-agent (browsers or tablet, pc,..) see random info. I need to detect some device and do a manipulation with this info. For example, for iOS users i have one kind of info, for android another, and so on... Also for pc/laptop user includes one kind of css (even logos, events, scripts,...) for android another css, for blackberry another css and so on.

I  think it's very important for absolutely responsive design.

Comment: I see what seems to be an answer to a question I have yet to see. Voting as unclear.

Comment: This isn't a code / blog repository.

Comment: Never read SO rules, just post your stuff.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it's not a question.. It's a solution)

Comment: What other answers do you have?

Comment: then there is no question. Solutions come "after" a question and I failed to see one.

Comment: We expect everything here to be in the form of a question and answer format. It's fine however to ask and then answer your own questions, provided you can articulate something as a good question that meets our normal standards.

Comment: @Flexo... ok... just do it

Comment: Thanks - that's not something I can do and keep your name on the answer, which was why I didn't just do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I did it like this... Create a detect.php file and include it to a document. If someone have ideas about it.. please...

```
<?php

$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //- Check user browser

/* Do not change anything under this line */
$iPod = stripos($useragent, "iPod"); 
$iPad = stripos($useragent, "iPad"); 
$iPhone = stripos($useragent, "iPhone");
$Android = stripos($useragent, "Android"); 
$iOS = stripos($useragent, "iOS"); 
$webOS = stripos($useragent, "webOS"); 
$Blackberry = stripos($useragent, "Blackberry");
$IEMobile = stripos($useragent, "IEMobile"); 
$OperaMini = stripos($useragent, "Opera mini"); 
$Flynx = stripos($useragent, "Flynx"); 
$Dolphin = stripos($useragent, "Dolphin");
$Meego = stripos($useragent, "Meego"); 
$Avantgo = stripos($useragent, "Avantgo"); 
$Bada = stripos($useragent, "Bada"); 
$Blazer = stripos($useragent, "Blazer");
$Compal = stripos($useragent, "Compal"); 
$Elaine = stripos($useragent, "Elaine"); 
$Fennec = stripos($useragent, "Fennec"); 
$Hiptop = stripos($useragent, "Hiptop");
$Iris = stripos($useragent, "Iris"); 
$Kindle = stripos($useragent, "Kindle"); 
$Lge = stripos($useragent, "Lge "); 
$Maemo = stripos($useragent, "Maemo");
$Midp = stripos($useragent, "Midp"); 
$Mmp = stripos($useragent, "Mmp"); 
$Netfront = stripos($useragent, "Netfront"); 
$OperaMobi = stripos($useragent, "Opera Mobi");
$Palm = stripos($useragent, "Palm"); 
$PalmOS = stripos($useragent, "Palm OS"); 
$Phone = stripos($useragent, "Phone"); 
$Plucker = stripos($useragent, "Plucker");
$Pocket = stripos($useragent, "Pocket"); 
$Psp = stripos($useragent, "Psp"); 
$Symbian = stripos($useragent, "Symbian"); 
$Treo = stripos($useragent, "Treo");
$Vodafone = stripos($useragent, "Vodafone");
$Wap = stripos($useragent, "Wap"); 
$WindowsCe = stripos($useragent, "Windows Ce"); 
$Xda = stripos($useragent, "Xda");
$Xiino = stripos($useragent, "Xiino"); 
$Kyivstar = stripos($useragent, "Kyivstar"); 
$Bolt = stripos($useragent, "Bolt"); 
$Boost = stripos($useragent, "Boost");
$Cricket = stripos($useragent, "Cricket"); 
$Docomo = stripos($useragent, "Docomo"); 
$Fone = stripos($useragent, "Fone"); 
$Mini = stripos($useragent, "Mini");
$Mobi = stripos($useragent, "Mobi"); 
$Pie = stripos($useragent, "Pie"); 
$Tablet = stripos($useragent, "Tablet"); 
$Wos = stripos($useragent, "Wos");
$Kitkat = stripos($useragent, "Kitkat"); 
$Mobile = stripos($useragent, "Mobile"); 
$GoBrowser = stripos($useragent, "GoBrowser"); 
$CLDC = stripos($useragent, "CLDC");
$uZardWeb = stripos($useragent, "uZardWeb"); 
$Doris = stripos($useragent, "Doris"); 
$Skyfire = stripos($useragent, "Skyfire"); 
$Smart = stripos($useragent, "Smart");
$MobileSafari = stripos($useragent, "Mobile Safari");

//-- Create a variable
$DEVICE = ($iPod||$iPad||$iPhone||$Android||$iOS||$webOS||$Blackberry||$IEMobile||$OperaMini||$Dolphin||$Meego||$Avantgo||$Bada||$Blazer||$Compal||$Elaine||
$Fennec||$Hiptop||$Iris||$Kindle||$Lge||$Maemo||$Midp||$Mmp||$Netfront||$OperaMobi||$Palm||$PalmOS||$Phone||$Plucker||$Pocket||$Psp||$Symbian||$Treo||$Wos||
$Vodafone||$Wap||$WindowsCe||$Xda||$Xiino||$Kyivstar||$Flynx||$Bolt||$Boost||$Cricket||$Docomo||$Fone||$Mini||$Mobi||$Pie||$Tablet||$Kitkat||$Mobile||$Smart||
$GoBrowser||$uZardWeb||$Doris||$Skyfire||$CLDC||$MobileSafari);

?>
```

Now you can use it like:

1. Include this file to all file that need to detect user device; you can include it once if you need
   For example: include_once ("path_to_file/detect.php");
2. Use variable $DEVICE anywhere you need infinity times like:

   ```
   <?php if (!$DEVICE) {echo 'This is for all desktop devices text';} else {echo 'This is for all mobile text';}
   ?>
   ```

or

!!! Also you can use it like this (if you need to separate info to different devices)

```
<?php if ($DEVICE=$iPhone) {echo 'This is for iphone devices text';} else if ($DEVICE=$Blackberry) {echo 'This is for Blackberry text';}
?>
```

That's it. All ingenious is simple! Use it and be happy! */ ?>